# Break conditions in different line

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I have a code to generate a equation in Latex. My problem is that How can I break line between a and b condition in the equation. With below code, the 0<=a<=10 and 0<=b<=10 are located in same line. I would like see as

```
  min
0<=a<=10  
0<=b<=10
```

Could you help me to do it? Thank all.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{0 \le a \le 1, 0 \le b \le 1} \Big\{ F(a,b) =a+b \Big\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\substack` from the [`mathtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, as that command is designed exactly to stack multiple subscripts. If you want more spacing between the two lines, you can add e.g. `\\[0.3ex]` (or any other amount) instead of `\\` in the argument to the `\substack` command.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2mm]{standalone} % Only to get minimal output
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\min_{\substack{0 \le a \le 1\\ 0 \le b \le 1}} \Big\{ F(a,b) =a+b \Big\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Output with `\substack{0 \le a \le 1\\[0.3ex] 0 \le b \le 1}`:

[image: Output with extra spacing]